# React reports error: Unexpected token, expected ","

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have simple Component:

```
import React,{Fragment, useState} from "react";  
import './AppClass.css';

const AppClass =(props) => {
    const [isTrue, setIsTrue] = useState(false)
    
    return(
        <>
            <hr/>
            <h1 className="h1-red"> 
                {props.msg}
            </h1>
        </>
        {isTrue &&
            <>
            </hr>
            </>
        }
    )
}

export default AppClass;
```

But it keep giving this error:

```
SyntaxError: C:\dev\my\go_apps\udemy_go_react\react-apps\my-app\src\AppClass.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (14:8)
  12 |             </h1>
  13 |         </>
> 14 |         {isTrue &&
     |         ^
  15 |             <>
  16 |             </hr>
  17 |             </>
ERROR in ./src/AppClass.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your react tree should contain only one top level node. Try something like this:

```js
import React,{Fragment, useState} from "react";  
import './AppClass.css';

const AppClass =(props) => {
    const [isTrue, setIsTrue] = useState(false);
    
    return(
        <>
            <hr/>
            <h1 className="h1-red"> 
                {props.msg}
            </h1>
            {isTrue &&
              <>
                <hr/>
              </>
            }
        </>
    )
}

export default AppClass;
```

Edit:
Plus you have used the tag `</hr>` which is treated as a closing tag in your example. Use `<hr/>` instead.